# MySQL: Selecting distinct with aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I'm having some trouble selecting a distinct order id from my orderItems table.

My orderItems table contains:
`orderId | itemId | orderedQuantity | inStockQuantity | backorderQuantity | isBackorderOfId | id`.

`orderedQuantity` is the total ordered amount, `inStockQuantity` is the quantity available at the time of purchase and `backorderQuantity` is the rest. `isBackorderOfId` correlates to the `id` column when an order item is a backorder of another order item.

My query is trying to select a distinct `orderId` of entries where the `backorderQuantity` < a `SUM(inStockQuantity)` where `isBackorderOfId` = `id`. This would result in a list if distinct order ids which have remaining backorders to be shipped.

Test data:

`orderId | itemId | orderedQuantity | inStockQuantity | backorderQuantity | isBackorderOfId | id
1 | 114 | 10 | 6 | 4 | 0  | 23
1 | 255 | 4  | 3 | 1 | 0  | 24
2 | 114 | 3  | 3 | 0 | 23 | 25`

Query:

```
SELECT items1.* FROM orderItems items1
LEFT JOIN orderItems items2 ON items2.isBackorderOfId = items1.id
WHERE items1.backorderQuantity > '0'
GROUP BY items2.isBackorderOfId
HAVING SUM(items2.inStockQuantity) < items1.backorderQuantity 
OR SUM(items2.inStockQuantity) IS NULL`
```

This results in both the first and second row which has the same `orderId`. I can't use SELECT DISTINCT because of the use of aggregate functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Distinct is similar to GROUP BY, you are already useing it. you have to change group by to the column you want to be distincted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  items1.orderId
FROM    orderItems items1
LEFT JOIN
        orderItems items2
ON      items2.isBackorderOfId = items1.id
GROUP BY
        items1.orderId
HAVING  COALESCE(SUM(items2.inStockQuantity), 0) < SUM(items1.backorderQuantity)
```